# Reactjs: Form with multiple inputs does not submit

Tags: reactjs

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/qotuxofalo/edit?js,output

(^ uses ES6 class, so please use a latest browser to test)

If I comment out the second `input` the form submits, but does not submit with more than 1 `input`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `input` of type `submit` to make the form work. Check the following examples. Adding that will submit the form on pressing enter. If you don't want that submit button, you can hide it using css.

Demo:

https://jsbin.com/mafafoxoji/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

If desired, you can also access the text as it is being entered using the `onChange` event handler: https://jsbin.com/moqogag/edit?js,output

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    console.log("CHANGING")
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
  render() {
    return React.DOM.form({ onChange: this.handleChange, action: "" }, [
      React.DOM.input({ type: "text" }),
      React.DOM.input({ type: "text" })
    ])
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App),
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```